# C++ std::map set and get using operator[]

Tags: operator-overloading, c++14, sparse-matrix, stdmap

I'm trying to build a 2D sparse matrix class using std::map, which should be called in (for example) the following way:

```
SparseMatrix<double> M(2,2);   // Create a new sparse matrix with 2 rows and 2 columns
M[{1,1}] = 3.1;                // Sets element {1,1} to 3.1
```

The following class can perform these tasks:

```
template < typename T > 
class SparseMatrix
{
    std::map< array<int, 2>, T> data;
    const array<int, 2> size;

public:
    SparseMatrix(const int rows, const int cols)
        : size({ rows, cols }) {}

    // []-operator to set and get values from matrix 
    T& operator[](const array< int,2 > indices)
    {
        // Check if given indices are within the size of the matrix
        if(indices[0] >= size[0] || indices[1] >= size[1])
            throw invalid_argument("Indices out of bounds");

        return data[indices];
    }
};
```

Using this class it is possible to create a new object and set the element, however, the []-operator is also used to get elements, for example:

```
std::cout << M[{1,1}] << std::endl;
```

The problem with this is that if this is used to get an element that is not set already, it creates a new part in the map with the given indices and a value of 0, which is undesired for a sparse matrix class, as the map should only contain the non-zero elements.

Is it possible to solve this problem with the []-operator by making a distinction between 'setting' and 'getting'? In case of 'getting' should the operator only return a 0 without adding it to the map.

Comment: function/operator doesn't know the context in which there are used (set/get). You may return a wrapper with `overload =` and `operator const T& ()`. (but doesn't handle `M[{1,1}].setInternal(/*..*/)`).

Comment: BTW, how do you handle `M[{1,1}] = 0;` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Good catch about the `M[{1,1}] = 0;`, I should implement another check for that as it shouldn't be stored in the map either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can differentiate between reading and writing by using a proxy instead of a `T&`. Only showing the relevant code:

```
template <typename T>
class SparseMatrixProxy {
    public:
    //for reading an element:
    operator T() const {
        // Check if given indices are within the size of the matrix
        if (indices[0] >= matrix.size[0] || indices[1] >= matrix.size[1])
            throw std::invalid_argument("Indices out of bounds");
        auto map_it = matrix.data.find(indices);
        if (map_it == matrix.data.end()) {
            return T{};
        }
        return map_it->second;
    }
    //for writing an element:
    auto operator=(const T &t) {
        //optional: when setting a value to 0 erase it from the map
        if (t == T{}) {
            matrix.data.erase(indices);
        } else {
            matrix.data[indices] = t;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

to be used in `SparseMatrix` like this:

```
// []-operator to set and get values from matrix
SparseMatrixProxy<T> operator[](const std::array<int, 2> indices) {
    return {*this, indices};
}
```

With usage:

```
SparseMatrix<double> M(2, 2); // Create a new sparse matrix with 2 rows and 2 columns
M[{{1, 1}}] = 3.1;            // Sets element {1,1} to 3.1
std::cout << M[{{1, 1}}] << '\n';
assert(M.mapsize() == 1); //1 element for index {1,1}
std::cout << M[{{0, 0}}] << '\n';
assert(M.mapsize() == 1); //still 1 element because reading doesn't insert an element
M[{{1, 1}}] = 0;
assert(M.mapsize() == 0); //0 elements because we set the only non-0 element to 0
```

[Complete](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9dc14448d97844a) [example](https://ideone.com/Z93ri5).

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do everything that I asked for, great! I am now trying to figure out if it is possible to eliminate the need for double curly brackets though.

Comment: @Merel The double curly braces are not required, my compiler just warned me about it: "suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]".

Answer (score 0):

There is `std::map::find` method. It returns an iterator and if it equals to `map.end()` then it means that the element is absent in the map.

Comment: But then it is still not known whether it's getting or setting. When it's setting the element it can both be absent and present, when it's getting it cannot be absent.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it's a pain in the backside. Luckily the clever C++11 bods realised this and gave us a new method: `at`.

Use the `at` method (available from the C++11 standard onwards), which does not do any insertion, although you still need a catch handler for a possible `std::out_of_range` exception.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at

Comment: You can do this and before C++11 with `find` method anyway (without range checking, but...)

Comment: Yeah, but `find` is not quite so clear. I've long been answering questions with C++11 as the baseline.

Comment: I looked at the `at`-method, but when 'setting' we **do** want to add an element to the map, even if it throws an exception. The `at`-method still does not make a distinction between setting and getting, right?

Comment: Not in that sense no. For the non-`const` version of `at`, you get back a non-`const` reference, that's all. For your specific usage I suggest you write your own stub function.

Answer (score 0):

It's cheaper from performance point of view to implement sparse matrix by creating own mapping, e.g via storing indices.

```
template<typename T>
class SparseMatrix
{
...
int m, n;
vector<T> values;
vector<int> cols;
vector<int> rows;
}

template<typename T> 
T SparseMatrix<T>::get(int row, int col) const 
 { 
    this->validateCoordinates(row, col); 


    int currCol = 0; 


    for (int pos = rows.at(row - 1) - 1; pos < rows.at(row) - 1; pos++) 
             { 
        currCol = cols.at(pos); 

        if (currCol == col) 
                    return vals.at(pos); 
         else if (currCol > col)  
            break; 
    } 


    return T(); 
 }

 template<typename T> 
SparseMatrix<T> & SparseMatrix<T>::set(T val, int row, int col) 
{ 
    // Validate coordinates here?

    int pos = rows.at(row - 1) - 1; 
    int currCol = 0; 


    for (; pos < rows.at(row) - 1; pos++) { 
        currCol = cols.at(pos); 


        if (currCol >= col) { 
            break; 
        } 
    } 


    if (currCol != col) { 
        if (!(val == T())) { 
            this->insert(pos, row, col, val); 
        } 


    } else if (val == T()) { 
        this->remove(pos, row); 


    } else { 
        vals.at(pos) = val; 
    } 


    return *this; 
 } 


template<typename T> 
void SparseMatrix<T>::insert(int index, int row, int col, T val) 
{ 

    vals.insert(vals.begin() + index, val); 
    cols.insert(cols.begin() + index, col); 

    for (int i = row; i <= this->m; i++)  
        rows.at(i) = rows.at(i) + 1; 

 }
```

And so on...